# I have to `bundle install` to every pane of tmux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tmux, ruby-2.3

I'm using **tmux** for **rails** project.
The purpose is to split pane. Such as, one pane for text editor, one pane for execute

```
rails s -b 0.0.0.0
```

etc.
It was very convenient until now.

Every new pane has forgotten that i executed:

```
bundle install
```

So that they required me to run `bundle install` again, when i create a new pane.
This is a huge pain. Somehow i want them to know that i executed it , but i don't know how to do it.

Thank you for your help.

---

Enviroment

- Mac mini (Mid 2011) OS X Yosemite
- Terminal (Not iTerm2)
- tmux -V -> 1.9a
- ruby -v -> ruby 2.3.1p112
- rails -v -> Rails 4.2.7.1
- rvm -v -> rvm 1.27.0

Note: I installed ruby 2.3.1 on a pane, but other new panes show ruby 2.1.1 ....

Comment: You need to provide a little more information. How is your ruby and rails setup? What's your OS? etc.

Comment: I wrote it! Thanks.

Comment: Did you try this in a new tmux session?

Comment: are you using rvm?

Comment: Yes, i'm using rvm for installing ruby.

Comment: @vee No, i'm doing this in one session.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but after reinstalled ruby and set latest ruby version as default, problem solved.

1) Installing ruby
I followed this site.
http://usabilityetc.com/articles/ruby-on-mac-os-x-with-rvm/

2) Setting latest ruby version

```
$ rvm --default use 2.3.1
```

Answer (score -1):

Attention the order. I think you should execute `bundle install` first, then split the pane.